# Автоматическое подстраивание размеров контрола под форму в C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть форма, на ней (например) DataGridView. Есть ли стандартные способы подстраивать размер контрола под изменяемый размер формы? Или исключительно всё обрабатывать вручную, отлавливая событие на форме?

Comment: Свойство `Anchor` посмотрите у контролов

Comment: Думаю, можно это переносить в ответы.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для этого предназначено свойство [`Anchor`, которое наследуется от класса `Control`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.control.anchor(v=vs.110).aspx)

Например, если вы установите кнопку, отступив 100 пикселей от низа окна (контейнера), и установите "якорь" на низ кнопки, то она будет сохранять этот отступ в 100 пикселей при изменениях размера формы.